# My UIImageView does not animate across the screen until it reaches the end

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewanimation

I am trying to bring the ball from one end of the screen to the other when the play button is clicked. My code does not redraw the ball until the ball reaches the right side of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post code as text and not images so it is searchable

Comment: You are using sleep function on main thread and inside while loop. After your loop ends the main thread has chance to draw you position changed view. Also if you want to animate views look at  Rakesha's answer. Also using sleep on main thread could cause huge problems in many directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose your code to move your ball inside a `UIView.animate` block.

```
UIView.animate(with: 1, animations: {
    //Code which animates your view
})
```

And do not use sleep if you are meaning for the code to run after the 1 second animation. Use completion block inside `UIView.animate`.

```
UIView.animate(with: 1, animations: {
    ball.center.x += balllVelocity
}, completion: (finished) in
    if finished {
        ball.center.x > view.frame.size.width {
            gameRunning = false
        }
    }
}
```

There are lots of things you can do with `UIView.animate`, i suggest you go through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate) to improve your animations.

Comment: this helped out a lot but I ran into a separate issue, I just posted it if you want to help me with that too. thanks!

Comment: Sure i'll try. Where is the question?

Comment: just posted it !

Comment: Please post your code there in the question. Not the image. I think i found the issue. But i need your code in the question as code, not as image.

Comment: I will post the code later, it says I have reached a question limit

Comment: @NorbuSonam You can undelete a question and edit it to add your code.